# Simple and elegant solution for hooking HP printers on network

Tags: linux, networking, printing, cups

I have server connected to LAN (running cups), but it's not in the same room as HP printers. I have [FPS-3003](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833118005), but somehow I never managed to bind CUPS to it's supported protocols.

I was thinking of buying cheap SOHO router and run cups on it. Any tips?

**EDIT:** printers are all conected with USB port.

Comment: Do you have just printers or MFC devices?

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the type of printer other than the brand, but I'll assume it's a USB printer?

The obvious answer would be to move the printer to the room with the server, hook it up, then share it out.

A second answer is to get a printer server device that supports the HP printer (jetdirect) and connect it to your LAN.

A third answer is to get a newer laser printer that has a jetdirect card built in, as they're not too expensive on the low end (and you might even find some on sale). In the long run I've found that to be the best answer, as it involves less workaround and configuration hassles and in tech, maintenance hassles trump ingenuity if it's something that more than just I need to use (like my family needing something printed out for school the next day).

If you're willing to consider buying other equipment to get network printing, you might want to consider $100 to $200 for a laserjet that supports built-in networking. Also nicer for configuration and monitoring.

Comment: "Maintenance hassles trump ingenuity". So true. Many times folks have been proud of 'hacks' but to me it's the contrast between IT admins choosing 'fun' vs 'best for the busness'.

Comment: When it comes to printers, I've been burned too many times on getting things duct-taped together. HP printers can be a royal @#%! with non-jetdirect solutions, and even then they can be touchy if it's an external sharing device. The best luck I've had is with their lasers and integrated jetdirects. If they last a couple years, the low end ones basically paid for themselves, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: I can't hook printer in server room. JetDirect sounds interesting, I'll google that. Any method beyond 50€ is not an option, I have some SOHO router chosen to be bought, WRT-ied and installed cups on it. But it's not a clean solution and definitely not easy also. Buying another printer is also out of options, I already have 3. The question is, what is the best way to hook those printers on CUPS server?

Comment: I have most luck using jetdirect IP printers. CUPS is what is normally used for most common Linux distro's now, used that at home and here to HP printers.

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc, this FPS-3003 thing supports both lpr and IPP, so it should be possible to hook CUPS to it from your server. What did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: I connected printer locally with plr and IPP successfuly, but when I set the ip address of FPS-3003 and connected it through that, it didn't work. I guess they dropped those protocols in support because they sucked:)